# How can I merge keys and values in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following data that is of this form:

```
{"('INTJ', 'INTP')\n": 3,
 "('INFJ', 'ENFP')\n": 3,
 "('ENFP', 'ENTJ')\n": 13,
.
.
.
 "('ENFP', 'ENFJ')\n": 11,
 "('ENFP', 'ESFP')\n": 4,
 "('ENFP', 'INTJ')\n": 8,
 "('ENFP', 'ESTP')\n": 2,}
```

which is stored in a dictionary, for ex:

```
myDict = {('ENFP', 'ESTP')\n:2,...,('ENFP', 'INTJ')\n": 8}
```

where `('ENFP', 'INTJ')\n` is a string and the value is an integer. There are ocurrences in the data where `('ENFP', 'ESFP')\n` has a value and `('ESFP','ENFP')\n` also has another value but they are practically duplicates!. However, this is only a specific example and there are many other ocurrences for different personality types. My goal is to ultimately have only one of these keys but have this key be the combined values of all the keys matched. And I want to do this for every key. I tried something like this:

```
for personality_1 in (total_personality_count_dict):

    for personality_2 in (total_personality_count_dict):

        if((personality_2[10:14] == personality_1[2:6]) and (personality_2[2:6] == personality_1[10:14]) and (personality_1[2:6] != personality_2[2:6])):

            update = {personality_1:total_personality_count_dict[personality_1]+total_personality_count_dict[personality_2]}

            total_personality_count_dict.update(update)

            total_personality_count_dict.pop(personality_2)
```

but I get an error that the dictionary changes size during iteration. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `"('INTJ', 'INTP')\n"` is an odd way to store a key. Did you mean to use tuples like `('INTJ', 'INTP')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you what's wrong: you can't change the size of `total_personality_count_dict` while iterating through it. You can't use `pop()`. Since you are doing addition, what you can do instead is update the value of the field you want to "remove" to 0, so any future addition done with it will not have any effect.

```
total_personality_count_dict[personality_2] = 0
```

And if you want a dictionary without `personality_2`, create a new dictionary and store the updates you want to keep there instead.